# Get last page visited

Tags: php, url, browser-history

I need to know if a person that comes to my website went from an another specific website. 
Example:

- User A visits www.youtube.com/myvideo and clicks on a link to my website.
- User B visits google, search my website and click the link.

Results Message on my page:

- User A: `Welcome! You already know how it works, register now!`
- User B: `Welcome! Please watch our video first at www.youtube.com/myvideo`

My question is:

1. Is it possible to know the last url the user visited before entering my page?
   I already tried `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` with PHP, but it's not working correctly and I read that does not work on all browsers.
2. Is there any language or php script to get this url, working on all browser correctly?

Comment: The referer is the only way to do this, and it's pretty reliable. How does it not work for you, what do you get?

Comment: As @Pekka mentioned, the referer is pretty reliable, it's supported by all browsers afaik.

Comment: if you control the link used by youtube you can add tracking to it

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The HTTP referer header is the only way.  This is the data that is given to you in PHP via `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`.

Note that this header will work in most cases.  Also note that it can be easily spoofed.

Comment: I know that, but that isn't a problem...
Thank you anyway.
Just wanted a opinion if was possible using other method.

Answer (score 2):

Why not add a GET variable to the link on youtube - www.yoursite.com/?referrer=youtube

For discretion and appearance you could rewrite the URL to something like www.yoursite.com/youtube